# How to configure active directory in windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, active-directory, server

I just installed Remote Server Administrative Tools (RSAT) on windows 7, and turned features on as mentioned in the installation guide. Now the Administrative Tools have been installed and successfully listed in the *All Programs* list of start menu.

I want to set up a local network. I want to create users/passwords, and give them access to shared drives with permissions, etc.

My questions is:

***How do I configure the Active Directory in windows 7 for the first time?***

Comment: Off-topic on Stack Overflow, and probably too broad for Server Fault.

Comment: Thanks @HarryJohnston for your comment. Actually, I searched on Stack Overflow, found similar questions and also exact tags. That's why I asked here.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic, Stack Overflow is only for programming questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RSAT is to remotely *manage* an Active Directory environment. It's not for *creating* an AD environment.

If you want to create an AD environment, you need Windows Server (2003/2008/2012) and install the 'Active Directory Domain Services' or 'Active Directory Lightweight Directory Services' role. There are instructions online on how to do that.

Comment: Thanks @GabrielLuci for your answer.